# How to disable autorun for removable media in ubuntu MATE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, autorun, mate, removable-storage

I've been looking a way to disable autorun for removable media in Ubuntu MATE but couldn't find it anywhere. I've looked on Google, Control Center of Ubuntu and even in gconf-editor but couldn't find the option to do so..

Anyone knows how to do that? will be very thankful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Caja, go to `Edit` | `Preferences` | `Media`.